# If both the eigenvector of $S_z$ and $\hat x$ form a basis for our Hilbert space, how can it have different dimensions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-spin

In almost all the books on Quantum Mechanics, it is stated that

> if $|\alpha \rangle $ is a ket describing the state of a system, then
>   any observable has a set of eigenvectors s.t those eigenvectors form a
>   basis for the Hilbert space of all possible states $|\beta \rangle $
>   that that system can be in.

However, if we consider a silver atom, $|S_z + \rangle$ is a possible state for that atom, and $|S_z \pm \rangle$ form a basis for the Hilbert space, since they are all the eigenvectors of $S_z$, so the dimension of our Hilbert space should be $2$.

However, if we consider the basis obtained by the eigenvectors of $\hat x$, we have infinitely many vectors, so the dimension is infinity, but these two statements contradicts with each other, so what am I missing in here ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us first be clear what the Hilbert space for a spinning particle with spin $s$ and position is: If $H_s$ is the Hilbert space of dimension $2s+1$ on which the spin operators live - the *spin space* - and $H_x$ is the ordinary position space (i.e. any separable Hilbert space with an irreducible representation of the canonical commutation relations on it, e.g. $L^2(\mathbb{R})$), then the total space of states of the spinning particle is $H_x\otimes H_s$, where $\otimes$ is the [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product). The operators on $H_x$ and $H_s$ extend to this space as $x\otimes \mathbf{1}_s$ and $\mathbf{1}_x\otimes S_i$, where $\mathbf{1}_i$ is the identity on $H_i$. So, for the spinning particle, you're actually taking about *different* operators when you say "position operator" or "spin operator" than if you were talking about $H_x$ or $H_s$ alone.

If your Hilbert space has both position and spin operators, then just writing $\lvert +\rangle$ to denote a certain value for spin doesn't make any sense - having a certain eigenvalue for spin does *not* uniquely identify a state, just like saying that a vector has eigenvalue 1 for the matrix
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
does not pick out a one-dimensional subspace, but a two-dimensional one. If the [eigenspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Eigenspaces,_geometric_multiplicity,_and_the_eigenbasis_for_matrices) associated to an eigenvalue is not one-dimensional, you can't use that eigenvalue to label a state uniquely.

In the case of a spin 1/2-object with position, the position operator is doubly degenerate - to each eigenvalue $x_0$ you have a space spanned by the states $\lvert x_0,+\rangle = \lvert x_0\rangle \otimes \lvert +\rangle$ and $\lvert x_0,-\rangle = \lvert x_0\rangle \otimes \lvert -\rangle$, which are now the state with eigenvalues $x_0$ for $x$ and $\pm1/2$ for $S_z$. Conversely, the spin operator is infinitely degenerate - to each eigenvalue $\pm1/2$ there are infinitely many states with that value.

In general, what you're looking for is the idea of a [complete set of commuting observables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_set_of_commuting_observables) (CSCO): If you have a CSCO with operators $A_i$, then that means that any given list of eigenvalues $a_i$ corresponds to a unique state, which we would usually denote $\lvert a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\rangle$. In the case of a spinning particle with position, position and spin form such a CSCO.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer, but this does not answer to my question; my problem lies in the fact that we have two different bases having different dimensions for the same space.

Comment: For example, what is $| x_0 \rangle $ in terms of the $| S_z \pm \rangle $ ? or $|S_z +\rangle $ in terms of $x_i$s ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas I have added a paragraph at the beginning of the answer that explains the nature of the combined space and added an explicit expression for the states $\lvert x_0,\pm\rangle$ in terms of the components.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification; I didn't know that. As a last question, if this kind of tensor product is only for states of spin observables, or is there any other states that live in different part of the whole space ? For example, is there a similar thing position and energy eigenstate like $H_x \oplus H_E$ ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas It is *mostly* for spin, but it in general can occur between observables between which there is no relation (spin and position have nothing to do with each other). Energy is a function of position/momentum so it doesn't make sense to think about it living on its own space. In general, if your algebra of observables decomposes as the direct sum of subalgebras - in this case the algebra of spin operators and the canonical commutation algebra of position and momentum - then the space of states will be the tensor product of a representation of first algebra with a rep of the second.